# TreeNode shows only on Child. Why?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Hello i use following code. Every time `actionPerformed` is called the selected node gets a new child node. However `JTree` shows only one child per node although it has more. Why is that?

```
private class SomeActionListener implements ActionListener{

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode _root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("ROOT");
    private JTree _tree;

    new SomeActionListener(){
        this._tree = new JTree(this._root);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)_tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(e.getWhen());
        selectedNode.add(newNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload the tree model after adding the new node:

```
((DefaultTreeModel)(_tree.getModel())).reload();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you don't fire any event to inform the tree that the model has changed.

Get the tree model and call [insertNodeInto()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#insertNodeInto%28javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode,%20javax.swing.tree.MutableTreeNode,%20int%29), and not only will the node be inserted, but an event will be sent to the JTree from the tree model to inform it that a node has been inserted, and that the view must be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, right after you add, update or remove a node:

```
this._tree.revalidate();
this._tree.repaint();
```